# Best way for drawing and coloring graphs

Tags: diagrams, graphs

Which library works better (convenient) for drawing/coloring (nodes) in Latex the following:
[image][image]

Comment: Ti*k*Z or pstricks or .... Which is most convenient depends, most of all on which you find most convenient. That is, this is asking for opinions, essentially, as there is no one answer. Ti*k*Z has automated graph-drawing algorithms, but you must use LuaTeX which isn't always an option for everyone. Otherwise, you can lay it out manually or as a matrix or as a commutative diagram or as chains or .... (And those are just Ti*k*Z options, really. pstricks offers more options besides.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{ auto-pst-pdf } %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX))
\usepackage{makebox} 

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.1cm, colsep=1.2cm, mnode = circle]%
%%%% Nodes
[name = I1] \infty &[fillcolor = Gainsboro!60!Lavender, fillstyle= solid, name = Z]
      \makebox*{$\infty$}{$ 0 $} & [name = I3] \infty & [name = I4] \infty \\
  [name = J1] \infty & [name = J2]\infty & [name = J3]\infty & [name = J4]\infty
%%%%% Connecting nodes
\foreach \S/\T in {J1/I1,I1/Z, Z/J2, J2/I3, J2/J3, J3/I3, J3/I4, J3/J4, I3/I4,I4/J4}{\ncline{\S}{\T}}
%%%%% Labelling nodes
\psset{labelsep = 3pt}
\foreach \N/\label in {I1/r, Z/s, I3/t, I4/u}{\nput{90}{\N}{\label}}
\foreach \N/\label in {J1/v, J2/w, J3/x, J4/y}{\nput{-90}{\N}{\label}}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

To obtain a diagram with shaded connection, one must the  `border=length` and `bordercolor=` keys, but due to the shading, the strategy is a little different: we build a matrix of `empty` nodes, connect these nodes and next add   `\pscirclebox`es  to these nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{ auto-pst-pdf } %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX))

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.1cm, emnode = p]%
%%%% Nodes
[name = Oa] &[name = Z] & [name = I3] & [name = I4] \\
  [name = J1] & [name =Ob] & [name = J3] & [name = J4] %
%%%%% Connections
\foreach \S/\T in { J3/I3, J3/I4, J3/J4, I3/I4,I4/J4}{\ncline{\S}{\T}}
\foreach \S/\T in {J1/Oa, Oa/Z, ,Z/Ob, Ob/I3,Ob/J3}{\ncline[border = 3.5pt, bordercolor = LightSlateGray, nodesep = -1pt]{\S}{\T}}
%%%%% Labels
\foreach \N/\label in {Oa/r, Z/s, I3/t, I4/u}{\nput[labelsep = 15pt]{90}{\N}{\label}}
\foreach \N/\label in {J1/v, Ob/w, J3/x, J4/y}{\nput[labelsep = 9pt]{-90}{\N}{\label}}
%%%% Coloured and non-coloured nodes
\psset{fillstyle = solid}
\foreach \node in {I3,I4, J1, J3, J4}{\rput(\node){\pscirclebox{\infty}}}
\psset{framesep = 4.4pt, fillcolor = DarkSlateGrey }
\rput(Oa){\pscirclebox[fillcolor = Gainsboro!60!Lavender]{1}}
\rput(Z){\pscirclebox{\color{white}0}}
\rput(Ob){\pscirclebox{\color{white}1}}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a very useful example. How can I add some shading to a given edge, say from x to y, and change the color of the text in the node? (sth similar to the second image above)

Comment: @DrimadesBoy: I've added  a code for the shading, which is slightly different from, but as short as the previous  code.